# Rust. Проблема с многопоточностью

Tags: многопоточность, rust

Пытаюсь освоить многопоточность в `Rust`. Прошу ответить на несколько вопросов. Читаю перевод `Rustbook`.

1. Мы оборачиваем данные в `sync::Mutex`, когда хотим использовать эти данные (эту переменную) в других потоках, чтобы не было "гонки данных"? То есть оборачиваем в `Mutex`, а там уже когда используем, то `lock()` и все остальные "становятся в очередь"?
2. Я сейчас о примере с Rustbook:

   ```
   use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
   use std::thread;
   fn main() {
           let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![1u32, 2, 3]));
           for i in 0..3 {
                   let data = data.clone();
                   thread::spawn(move || {
                       let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
                       data[i] += 1;
               });
       }
       thread::sleep_ms(50);
   }
   ```

Какие-то странные и непонятные действия. Ну, хорошо, связали data с вектором, который обернут в Mutex, но зачем ещё в Arc? Внутри цикла зачем-то делаем копию и связываем с data, потом уже в замыкании опять новая переменная data. 
Объясните пожалуйста.

3. Моя попытка сделать десять потоков и в каждом из них прибавлять по единице к data. Неработающая попытка:

   ```
   use std::thread;
   use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

   fn main() {
       let mut data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

       let handles: Vec<_> = (0..10).map(|_| {
           thread::spawn(move|| { 
               data.lock();
               data += 1; //binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `alloc::arc::Arc<std::sync::mutex::Mutex<_>>
           })
       }).collect();

       for h in handles {
           h.join();
       }

   }
   ```

Почему опять ему (компилятору) не нравится?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В книге очень подробно разобран этот пример с вариантами что будет без мьютексов и что будет без `Arc`:

> `Arc<T>` - является атомарным указателем со счетчиком ссылок.
>   «Атомарный» означает, что им безопасно обмениваться между потоками.
>
> Чтобы гарантировать, что его можно безопасно использовать из
>   нескольких потоков, `Arc<T>` предполагает наличие еще одного свойства у
>   вложенного типа. Он предполагает, что T реализует типаж Sync. В нашем
>   случае мы также хотим, чтобы была возможность изменять вложенное
>   значение. Нам нужен тип, который может обеспечить изменение своего
>   содержимого лишь одним пользователем одновременно. Для этого мы можем
>   использовать тип `Mutex<T>`

Единственное что там вводит в заблуждение - используется затенение переменных, так что там три разных переменных с одинаковым именем `data`.

Вот рабочий код вашего примера:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let handles: Vec<_> = (0..10).map(|_| {
        let xd = data.clone();// (1)
        thread::spawn(move|| { 
            let mut x = xd.lock().unwrap();// (2)
            *x+=1;// (3)
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join();
    }

    println!("{:?}",data)
}
```

По пунктам что было не так:

1. Вы пытаетесь непосредственно обратиться к переменной `data`. Так как для типа `Arc` не реализован типаж неявного копирования `Copy`, то первый же поток захватит право владения переменной и она будет недоступна для остальных потоков (и для основного тоже). Поэтому используется явное клонирование указателя `data.clone()`.
2. Функция `lock()` возвращает специальный объект `MutexGuard<T>` дополнительно завернутый в `LockResult`. Когда этот объект будет освобожден защелка будет отпущена. Поэтому результат возвращаемый `lock()` нужно сохранить в переменную. `unwrap()` вытаскивает `MutexGuard` из `LockResult`. К тому же этот объект нужен для доступа к самим данным.
3. Для доступа к данным внутри `MutexGuard<T>` нужно разыменовать то что мы получили в п.2.